# The usage of Newton's method in nonlinear regression

Tags: optimization, econometrics, nonlinear-regression

Would you please give an intuitive illustration of Newton's Method, when we deal with nonlinear regression?
 Basically I understand that if we can use Taylor's theorem to expand the RSS function of parameter beta, we can change it into quadratic form, and minimize RSS w.r.t parameter. Please give me a multivariate example by using gradient and Hessian matrix.
Sorry I intend to input equation and function here, but I have no idea how to use LaTeX code here.

Comment: @Weijlie You can use $\LaTeX$ code in the usual way, i.e. by enclosing your expression with `$` (inline) or `$$` (display). Also, please make your title shorter (e.g., "Intuitive illustration of Newton's method in nonlinear regression").

Comment: The *Mathematica* help page has a nice illustration with explanations: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationNewtonsMethodRoot.html .